# Python error when executing add-apt-repository on Parrot OS 5.0

Tags: linux, apt, python, parrotsec

I installed the new Parrot OS 5.0 yesterday but I was getting a Python error when trying to add a new repository. It does not mater which repository I try to add, the same error raises over and over. Here is an output when I execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 276, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 292, in refresh
    self.matcher.match(source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 484, in match
    if (re.search(template.match_uri, source.uri) and
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 2
```

I already checked if the `sources.list.d` folder exists and it's there with the file `parrot.list`. My Python version is `Python 3.9.2`. Here is the content of my `parrot.list`:

```
## This file provides the default APT repositories for Parrot Security
## These repositories are used to fetch new software and system updates

###############################
## Default Parrot Repository ##
###############################
## The 'parrot' repository provides all the Parrot software considered
## stable and tested.
##
## the main suite provides the base system plus all the software released
## under a free and open source license compatible with the Debian guidelines.
##
## the contrib suite provides additional free software that depends on third
## party software not provided by the main suite. it usually means that such
## packages depend on non-free software.
##
## the non-free suite provides additional packages that don't comply with
## the Debian Free Software Guidelines. They are mostly proprietary software.
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot main contrib non-free

######################
## Security Updates ##
######################
## The 'parrot-security' repository provides time sensitive security updates
## that have to be delivered to end users as fast as possible
##
## this repo should always be enabled in your system
##
## we strongly recommend to NOT use mirrors for this repo, but only
## access security updates from our official domains or CDNs.
##
## a mirror server could take too much time to fetch an important update,
## leaving you without security updates for a timespan outside of our control
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security main contrib non-free

###############
## Backports ##
###############
## The stable repository contains software that is considered stable the day of
## the release. such packages receive only security and stability updates that
## don't introduce new features and don't drop old ones.
##
## the 'backports' repository provides feature updates to many packages, and
## even external software that was originally excluded from the stable release.
##
## disable it if you prefer stability and reliability over bleeding edge features
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports main contrib non-free

#######################
## Updates / Testing ##
#######################
## The 'parrot-updates' repository provides updates before they are made available
## to 'parrot'. this repo is mostly meant to be used by developers and beta testers 
## to extensively test updates before they are migrated to the main repository
##
## we suggest not to enable it, as it may introduce untested bugs and make the
## system unstable. updates are delivered as fast as possible (within a week)
## so you are not missing anything important with this disabled (unless you are a dev)
#deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-updates main contrib non-free


##############################
## Source Code Repositories ##
##############################
## These repositories provide the debian source artifacts of the packages
## in the corresponding repos in the form of dsc files and the corresponding
## tarballs
##
## you only need these repositories if you intend to download the source code
## of a package and re-compile it yourself with debian-compliant build tools
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-updates main contrib non-free



##########################################################
## How to configure mirror servers for faster downloads ##
##########################################################
## The Parrot system is configured by default to use the central
## parrot archive directors. The Parrot directors are special servers that
## collect all the requests of the users and redirect them to the nearest
## download server available for the user who made the request.
##
## The Parrot Mirror Network is secured by centralized digital signatures
## and the mirrors can't inject fake updates. If an evil mirror tries to inject
## a fake package, Parrot OS will automatically refuse to download and install it.
##
## To configure a mirror, you have to replace the original URL with the URL
## Provided by the mirror
##
## Example:
## If you live in Italy and you want to take advantage of the GARR mirror,
## Replace
##  deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot main contrib non-free
## With
##  deb https://parrot.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/parrot parrot main contrib non-free
##
## IMPORTANT NOTES:
## do NOT use mirrors for the parrot-security repository. use them
## exclusively for 'parrot', 'parrot-backports' and 'parrot-updates'
##
## LIST:
## A full and updated list of official mirrors is available here:
##      https://www.parrotsec.org/docs/mirrors-list.html
##
##

##########################
## Some popular mirrors ##
##########################
## This is a non-comprehensive, and not-updated list of mirrors
## that we leave here a a quick reference. some of them are
## worldwide, meaning that they have several nodes around the world
## and the fastest one is picked automatically (CDN).
## others are tight to a specific region of the world.

## Worldwide - Parrot - automatically redirects to the fastest of all the mirrors
#deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Worldwide - Parrot - core servers with no redirection
#deb https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Wordlwide - Azure - Uses the Azure CDN platform
#deb https://edge1.parrot.run/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Wordlwide - Aliyun - Uses the AlibabaCloud mirrors behind their worldwide CDN
#deb deb https://mirrors.aliyun.com/parrot parrot main contrib non-free

## US Massachussetts - SIPB MIT University
#deb http://mirrors.mit.edu/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## US California - OCF Berkekey University
#deb https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## US Virginia - Leaseweb
#deb https://mirror.wdc1.us.leaseweb.net/parrot parrot main contrib non-free

## Germany - Halifax RWTH-Aachen University
#deb https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/parrotsec/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Italy - GARR Consortium
#deb https://parrot.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Netherlands - Nluug
#deb https://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Russia - Yandex
#deb https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Brazil - Sao Paulo University
#deb http://sft.if.usp.br/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## Singapore - 0x
#deb https://mirror.0x.sg/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free

## China - USTC University
#deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/parrot parrot main contrib non-free


## We strongly invite you to visit https://www.parrotsec.org/docs/mirrors-list.html
## to find the mirror that better fits your needs
```

Comment: What repo did you try to add, and how? Edit your question to include this, and please include the contents of your `parrot.list`.

Comment: @Panki I tried with some repos, the last one was ```ppa:grumbel/ppa``` to add drivers for xbox controller, here is the command: ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa```